# Group query results in batches of Python

Tags: python, django

I have a query.

```
messages = Message.objects.all()
```

I will be sending the results 'messages' to a called function `bulk_send()` but this can only accepted 500 messages from this query at a time

So I was thinking, is there a way to split the results into batches for example

```
 bulk_send(messages first 500)
 bulk_send(messages next 500)
 bulk_send(messages the remaining )
```

but this won't work because I never know how many results are in messages there could be 200 or a million, either way bulk_send and only accept 500 at any given time.

Comment: You may find [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1170/) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total = Message.objects.all().count()
for i in xrange(0,total,500):
   batch = Message.objects.all()[i:500]
```

Comment: batch = Message.objects.all()[i:i+500] is the correct statment !

Answer (score 1):

```
all_messages = Message.objects.all()

if all_messages.count() == 0:
    return

n = all_messages.count() / 500

for i in range (n if n else 1):
    messages = all_messages[i*500:(i+1)*500]
    bulk_send(messages)
```

Comment: what would happen if I only had 200 in this example?

Comment: my bad, i update my answer. n should at least 1 if all_messages.count() > 0